# NASM Windows 64 bits y DEV C++

Tags: nasm

Estoy aprendiendo assembler desde 0 (vengo de lenguajes como C y C++).
Desafortunadamente mi libro tiene comandos que a aplican a LINUX.

Creé un "`hello.asm`" con dev c++
ejecute el comando:  `nasm -felf64 hello.asm`
y creó un archivo "`hello.o`"

Segun el libro tengo que ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
nasm -felf64 hello.asm -o hello.o 
ld -o hello hello.o
chmod ux hello
```

pero esos comandos no funcionan en Windows.

Como es en windows?
Existe manera de linkear los archivos que uno programa en `c,c++` en el IDE dev c++ con nasm para autogenerar el .asm?

Comment: Intenta con `nasm -f win32 hello.asm -o hello.o`

Comment: Si, son settings y comandos orientados a linux. Pero la teoría en windows es la misma, se genera un objeto y luego se pasa el linker. Revisa esto, por si te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767917/how-to-link-a-simple-program-in-windows-with-mingw-gcc